# React native Invariant Violation: Callback with id 2 error

Tags: react-native

I'm getting an error on my iOS simulator when I'm in Chrome debug mode, it says: Invariant Violation: Callback with id 2: RCTAppState.getCurrentAppState() not found. Any ideas what this might be related to? I've tried stripping down my pages to the bare minimum but it hasn't resolved the error.

Answer (score 11):

make you sure, you don't opened tab with debugger twice.

Comment: Thanks that's fixed the error! Such a simple thing too.

Comment: Ugh. This just made me pull my hair out for an hour before I came across this. So simple, and so silly. Thank you.

Comment: You can use also chrome extension https://github.com/siwymilek/React-Native-Prevent-Double-Tab-Chrome-Extension